# Flutter App doesn't work when changing package name

Tags: flutter, dart

When I tried to change the package name in MainActivity.kt inside kotlin the app doesn't run

This error:

```
e: /Users/dma/development/flutter_share/android/app/src/main/kotlin/com/example/souqmubtath/MainActivity.kt: (8, 7): Redeclaration: MainActivity
e: /Users/dma/development/flutter_share/android/app/src/main/kotlin/dev/dhari/souqmubtath/MainActivity.kt: (8, 7): Redeclaration: MainActivity

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.                                

* What went wrong:                                                      
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.                    
> Compilation error. See log for more details                           

* Try:                                                                  
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org                              

BUILD FAILED in 27s                                                     
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                                  
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                        27.6s
Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You haven't changed your package name correctly,

Just go to the following path

**android > app > src >main > kotlin**

Inside that you will find one more package like **your_package_name** containing MainActivity file.

In your case it is like, "com.example.souqmubtath "

So to change it properly, just go to your android manifest file, from there just find package="com.example.souqmubtath"

Just select com.example.souqmubtath and refactor it.

For refactor either **select the package name** -> **right click** on it -> **Refactor** -> **Rename**.
                                          **OR**
Just **select the package name** and use refactor rename shortcut which is **Shift+F6**

You can rename it to your desired package name. In your case it is like "dev.dhari.souqmubtath"

Also, go to your **android > app > build.gradle** file path. Inside the file and **defaultConfig{}** find out **applicationId** and refactor it as well to the same name as your package name.

Comment: or look in `android > app > src >main > kotlin` for duplicated files named MainActivity in different packages. Remove the files you don't need and keep the one you need.

Answer (score 5):

Problem encountered on Flutter

packagename: com.[companyname].[binairyname]

In my case there were two folders in android/app/src/main/kotlin/com/

In this folder there were :

- example/binary/*
- companyname/binary/*

Since after a flutter create command the companyname in packagename are init to example, I deduced that the example folder should be deleted

Problem solved

```
flutter --version
Flutter 2.2.3 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision f4abaa0735 (9 weeks ago) • 2021-07-01 12:46:11 -0700
Engine • revision 241c87ad80
Tools • Dart 2.13.4
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a useful package for changing it but it works well with android, I didn't try for IOS.

Firstly install the package:

change_app_package_name: ^1.0.0

Then in the terminal in your project paths do these commands:

flutter pub get

Then write the line below and use the unique name you want after com. then press enter:

flutter pub run change_app_package_name:main com.demo.flutter_app
will update files and delete old package names.

Answer (score 1):

Encountered this error about ~duplicate~ **MainActivity.kt**,

removing the `MainActivity.kt` under **[../com/example]** resolved it

```
  e: /Users/dma/development/flutter_share/android/app/src/main/kotlin/com/example/souqmubtath/MainActivity.kt: (8, 7): Redeclaration: MainActivity
  e: /Users/dma/development/flutter_share/android/app/src/main/kotlin/dev/dhari/souqmubtath/MainActivity.kt: (8, 7): Redeclaration: MainActivity
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to update the package name inside the `MainActivity.kt` on the top.

If this is correct then check your manifest file, is there package name updated or not?

Only the two reasons that your app not working.